# Python: How to extract only complete words in a character chunk of x characters?

Tags: python, string, loops

Consider the string
`s = "you'll never know the truth"`

if I want to split this string into 15 characters (`s[:15]`) I get `"you'll never kn"`

What I want to do with this new string is only extract the *complete* words ('you'll' and 'never' in this case) and then return that string, and a way for my loop to start at the beginning of the incomplete word. Any idea how to do this?

edit: as PM 2Ring has mentioned, I am only concerned with spacing acting as word separators for the moment. Once I figure that out I'll deal with commas, hyphens, newlines and the such.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is space the _only_ word separator we need to test for? Or do we also need to deal with stuff like non-break space, hyphens, tabs, newlines... ? How do we handle words that contain more than 15 chars?

Comment: pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis is a word!

Comment: @PM2Ring, Thank you for catching that. Yes, for now I'm only concerned with spaces being the main separator. When I figure this out, then I will deal with the rest you have mentioned.

Comment: @InAFlash thanks for your reply. The problem with s.split() is that it still contains non complete characters. When I break a long string into a 15 word chunk, even words that are cut of, such as `kn` in this case will be contained in the split function.

Comment: @InAFlash We don't need to worry about that here. We just need to look for the spaces that delimit words.

Comment: @InAFlash He then wants to repeat the process so he can capture "know the". Etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the standard library's `textwrap` module.

```
import textwrap

s = "you'll never know the truth, said the artificially emlengthened example string"

for chunk in textwrap.wrap(s, 15):
    print(chunk)
```

outputs

```
you'll never
know the truth,
said the
artificially
emlengthened
example string
```

Comment: Awesome, just what I needed, thanks so much! I'm new to programming and this is my first app, is knowing all the standard library's modules and methods just a matter of time spent coding?

Comment: It's worth knowing the tools that exist in the toolbox, but it's not worth knowing every little detail about them by heart. I'd suggest at least skimming through the Python library reference :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to slice off a substring of the desired maximum chunk size (15 in this case), and use the `str.rfind` method to locate the last space. If we don't find a space, then spit out the whole chunk.

A nice Pythonic way to do this is in a generator.

```
def word_split(src, chunksize):
    # Clean up any newlines and duplicate spaces
    src = ' '.join(src.split())
    while src:
        chunk = src[:chunksize]
        idx = chunk.rfind(' ')
        if idx == -1:
            # no space found
            idx = chunksize
        yield chunk[:idx]
        src = src[idx+1:]

# test

src = """you'll never know  the truth, or a way for my   loop
to start at the beginning of  the incomplete word like this
pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis"""
chunksize = 15

for s in word_split(src, chunksize):
    print(repr(s), len(s))
```

**output**

```
"you'll never" 12
'know the' 8
'truth, or a' 11
'way for my' 10
'loop to start' 13
'at the' 6
'beginning of' 12
'the incomplete' 14
'word like this' 14
'pneumonoultrami' 15
'roscopicsilicov' 15
'lcanoconiosis' 13
```

Comment: i think, based on his last comment in the OP, he also wants yo ignore non-english words,